# Multiple params with render function in for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, parameters

I want to create multiple .html with R, by using a for loop including the rmarkdown::render function and containing multiple parameters (params) with conditions. How can I set multiple params in this case?

I've tried the following code that doesn't work.

**Exemple of the Rmd template:**

````
---
title: "The ranking of `r params$word` companies"
output: distill::distill_article
params:
  country: "USA"
  word: "American"
  pays: "the United States"
---

Figure 1. Number of businesses in `r params$pays`      

```{r}
dataGraph1 <- filter(dataGraph7, country==params$country)
plot(dataGraph1)
```
It is interesting to observe the progress of those `r params$word` businesses.
````

**The for loop created to produce the html from the Rmd template with different params:**

```
# Directory containing input (and output) files
directory <- "~/thelink"

for (country in c("Canada", "USA", "France", "Germany", "UK", "Japan")) {
  if (country == "Canada"){
    word <- "Canadian"
    pays <- "Canada"
  } else if (country == "USA"){
    word <- "American"
    pays <- "the United States"
  } else if (country == "Germany") {
    word <- "German"
    pays <- "Germany"
  } else if (country == "France") {
    word <- "French"
    pays <- "France"
  } else if (country == "UK") {
    word <- "British"
    pays <- "The United Kingdom"
  } else (country == "Japan") {
    word <- "Japanese"
    pays <- "Japan"
  }
  input <- paste0(directory, "/", "iri2015template", ".Rmd")
  output <- paste0(directory, "/","iri2015", country, ".html")
  try(rmarkdown::render(input, params = list(country = country, word = word, pays = pays), output_file = output))
}
```

**The error:**

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
>   input <- paste0(directory, "/", "iri2015template", ".Rmd")
>   output <- paste0(directory, "/","iri2015", country, ".html")
Error in paste0(directory, "/", "iri2015", country, ".html") : 
  object 'country' not found
>   try(rmarkdown::render(input, params = list(country = country, word = word, pays = pays), output_file = output))
Error in rmarkdown::render(input, params = list(country = country, word = word,  : 
  object 'output' not found
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>
```

What I want the for loop to produce is an html named iri2015USA.html when country == USA with the other params as word == American and pays == the United States.

It should produce an html named iri2015Canada.html when country == Canada with the other params as word == Canadian and pays == Canada.

etc.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *I've tried the following code that doesn't work.* ... is not helpful for us. What does the code currently do? Any errors or undesired results?

Comment: @Parfait I've edited the question with the error produced.

Comment: I think you are missing an `if` in `else (country == "Japan") {`. If I'm correct, then this has nothing to do with the title of your question.

Comment: @42- I've check how to write an if else statement and it seems correct the way it is.  https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/if-else-statement/

Comment: Marine, find a working example of `if (cond) { ... } else (cond1) { ... }` (no "if"). None of the examples on your datamentor link suggest `else (cond)`.

Comment: The cited reference has no `(cond)` expression in the terminal else clause. If you have a `(cond)` you need an `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `switch` used similarly to other languages (Java, C#, C++, PHP, Perl):

```
for (country in c("Canada", "USA", "France", "Germany", "UK", "Japan")) {
  switch (country,           
          "Canada" = {
             word <- "Canadian"
             pays <- "Canada"
          },    
          "USA" = {
             word <- "American"
             pays <- "the United States"
          }, 
          "Germany" = {
             word <- "German"
             pays <- "Germany"
          }, 
           "France" = {
             word <- "French"
             pays <- "France"
          },
          "UK" = {
             word <- "British"
             pays <- "The United Kingdom"
          },
          "Japan" = {
             word <- "Japanese"
             pays <- "Japan"
          })

  input <- paste0(directory, "/", "iri2015template", ".Rmd")
  output <- paste0(directory, "/","iri2015", country, ".html")

  tryCatch(rmarkdown::render(input, 
                             params = list(country = country, word = word, pays = pays), 
                             output_file = output)
           , error = function(e) print(e)
  )              
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I've done something like that, I've posted my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
countries <-  c("Germany",
                "France",
                "UK",
                "USA",
                "Japan",
                "Canada")

for (country in countries) {
  nationality <- switch (country,
                         "USA" = "American",
                         "France" = "French",
                         "Germany" = "German",
                         "UK" = "British",
                         "Japan" = "Japanese",
                         "Canada" = "Canadian")
  name <- switch (country,
                  "USA" = "the United States",
                  "France" = "France",
                  "Germany" = "Germany",
                  "UK" = "the United Kingdom",
                  "Japan" = "Japan",
                  "Canada" = "Canadian")
  input <- paste0(directory, "/", "iri2015template", ".Rmd")
  output <- paste0(directory, "/","iri2015", country, ".html")
  rmarkdown::render(input, params = list(country = country, nationality = nationality, name = name), output_file = output)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider even `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) which is the elementwise loop through equal-length vectors (i.e., columns of a data frame) which scales to data without adjusting `switch` or `if` code.

```
country_df <- data.frame(
     country = c("Germany", "France", "UK", "USA", "Japan", "Canada"),
     nationality = c("German", "French", "British", "American", "Japanese", "Canadian"),
     names = c("Germany", "France", "the United Kingdom", 
               "the United States", "Japan", "Canada")
)

# USER-DEFINED FUNCTION OF MULTIPLE ARGS
html_build <- function(country, nationality, names) {    
  input <- paste0(directory, "/", "iri2015template", ".Rmd")
  output <- paste0(directory, "/","iri2015", country, ".html")

  rmarkdown::render(input, 
                    params = list(country = country, 
                                  nationality = nationality, 
                                  name = names), 
                    output_file = output)
}

# ELEMENT WISE (LOOP-HIDING) CALL
Map(html_build, country_df$country, country_df$nationality, country_df$names)

# with(country_df, Map(html_build, country, nationality, names))           # LESS WORDY
```